# Do $L^2$ convergence and continuity imply pointwise convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

It is said [here](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~grigoryan/124B/lecs/lec5.pdf) that $L^2$ convergence and continuity imply pointwise convergence (just before paragraph $5.2$) but I can't find how to prove it. Does anyone see how ?

Comment: It seems wrong to me. Consider triangles of the hieght $1$, with base of the form $[k 2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n}]$ (varying over whole segment $[0,1]$). They all continuous and converge in $L_2$ to continuous function $0$ but convergence is not pointwise.

Comment: If it were really simple, then why does he go on and prove things like Theorem 5.5(i) ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's wrong : $f_n(x) = \log(n)e^{-nx}$ over $[0,1]$ is a sequence of continuous functions which converges in $L_2$ toward the zero function.
However, $f_n(0) \rightarrow +\infty$

Comment: This counterexample is just what I needed. For the one given by Norbert in the comments, we have convergence of subsequences, which is not the case here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Convergence in $L^2$ does not imply convergence everywhere but it does imply point wise convergence almost everywhere. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series