# Why does weak-$L^2$ convergence not imply pointwise convergence for continuous functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, weak-convergence, fake-proofs

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372720/do-l2-convergence-and-continuity-imply-pointwise-convergence) shows that $L^2$ convergence does not show pointwise convergence, even when the functions involved are continuous.  This strongly contradicts my intuition, because I thought that weak-$L^2$ convergence sufficed for the same.

What is wrong with the following proof?

> Let $\{\psi_\delta\}_{\delta}$ be approximate identities and continuous $\{f_n\}\rightharpoonup f_{\infty}$ in $L^2$.  We claim $f_{\infty}(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}{f_n(0)}$.
>
> To see this, fix $\epsilon$.  There exists $\alpha$ such that for any $\delta<\alpha$ and continuous $g$, $$\epsilon>|g(0)-\langle g,\psi_{\delta}\rangle|$$  For such $\delta$, then, $$\epsilon+\langle g,\psi_{\delta}\rangle>g(0)$$  Now let $g=|f_{\infty}-f_n|$; we have $$\epsilon+\langle|f_{\infty}-f_n|,\psi_{\delta}\rangle>|f_{\infty}(0)-f_n(0)|$$  As $\{f_n\}\rightharpoonup f_{\infty}$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\langle|f_{\infty}-f_n|,\psi_{\delta}\rangle}=0$ for any $\delta$.  So take $n\to\infty$; we obtain $$\epsilon>\limsup_{n\to\infty}{|f_{\infty}(0)-f_n(0)|}$$  Now take $\epsilon\to0^+$.

#### Worked example

We can test this with the example from the cited question: in $L^2([0,1])\cap C([0,1])$, take $f_n(x)=\ln{\!(n)}e^{-nx}$ and $\psi_{\delta}(x)=\frac{1}{\delta}\chi_{[0,1]}\left(\frac{x}{\delta}\right)$.  As $n\to\infty$, $$\|f_n\|_2=\ln{(n)}\sqrt{\frac{1-e^{-2n}}{2n}}\to0$$ so $\{f_n\}_n\to0$, and thus $\{f_n\}_n\rightharpoonup0$.

$f_n(0)=\ln{(n)}$, so we should expect $$\lim_{\delta\to0^+}{\int_0^1{f_n(x)\psi_{\delta}(x)\,dx}}=\ln{(n)}$$  On the other hand, weak convergence should give $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\int_0^1{f_n(x)\psi_{\delta}(x)\,dx}}=\int_0^1{0\cdot\psi_{\delta}(x)\,dx}=0$$

Well, $$\int_0^1{f_n(x)\psi_{\delta}(x)\,dx}=\frac{\ln{(n)}(1-e^{-n\delta})}{n\delta}$$  Taking $n\to\infty$ does yield $0$, and $\delta\to0^+$ yields $\ln{(n)}$!  What gives?

Comment: The limits do not commute!

Comment: @Ian: Yes.  The idea here is that, by taking the $\delta$ limit after the $n$ limit, we "spread out" the values of $x$ that affect evaluating $f_n(x)$, so that the value $f_n(0)$ becomes "visible" to the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: Right, in the example they don't commute. At the level of this proof, that means that there are continuous functions with very bad modulus of continuity at $0$, which are arbitrarily hard to approximately evaluate at $0$ using the approximate identity $\psi_\delta$. This is why @gerw 's answer is correct.

Comment: As a side remark: Even if all the functions are continuous, strong $L^2$ convergence does not implies pointwise convergence everywhere. Just think of $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @MaoWao: yes; discovering that fact is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your attempt is:

> To see this, fix $\epsilon$.  There exists $\alpha$ such that for any $\delta<\alpha$ and continuous $g$, $$\epsilon>|g(0)-\langle g,\psi_{\delta}\rangle|$$

This is not true. Instead, you have the following: For every $g$, there exists $\alpha$ such that for $\delta < \alpha$ you get
$$\epsilon>|g(0)-\langle g,\psi_{\delta}\rangle|$$

Comment: I see; there is a hidden uniformity assumption.  Thank you!